# how to get all items of has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a post model that has many tags through taggings.
let's say:

```
@posts = Post.followed_by(@user)
```

I want to get all tags of @posts.

I can do it with something like:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  @tags << post.tags
end
```

how can I do it in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: {post_id: @posts.map(&:id)})
```

If `@posts` is a relation (not an array), you can simplify your query:

```
Tag.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: {post_id: @posts})
```

Comment: thanks! both options work

can you please explain those queries ?

Comment: What exactly do you want me to explain? Btw, if both are working then use the second one. The first one leads to two SQL-queries because it fetches id's of every post in `@posts` and then uses them to issue another query for fetching tags. The second one issues one query (id's aren't passed to application to create anoter query) so it's faster.